# Grails Domain Class String List

Tags: list, grails, grails-domain-class

i try to make a String list in Grails.
My part therefore are:

```
class Name{
static hasMany = [names: String] }
```

I created also a Controller for the Class and added there:

```
static scaffold = Name
```

So far it is working but on in the view there are only the name of the String but i can not add any inputs to the list.

So therefore I'm looking for a solution, hope someone can help.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You question is not very clear because of that what you want.

If i have understood you question here are my answers to you :

1.If you use `scaffolding true` grails will automatically generate pages and codes based on your `domain configuration`, if you need more `inputs as you said` `add more domain variables like`.i.e

```
  class Name{
    static hasMany = [names: String]
    //to see more inputs add them here
    String description 
  }
```

You have only one domain called `Name` and then what did you expect to see other more inputs you need other more member variables or property's..
If you are not satisfied with the component that grails created fro you can change it on `.gsp` file.

Great resource here http://goo.gl/f7XV8I

Let me know of further assistance...